# php call private variable inside another private variable error

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, variables

My `PHP Code`:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class admin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('ajax');
    }

    private $password = 'password';

    private $login_details = array(
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => sha1('salt'.$this->password)
    );
```

the above `code` returns the following `PHP` error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

i am using codeigniter but i dont think that this has something to do with the problem since its PHP based...

Comment: @safarov i know that, i cant see how to fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class members have to be initialized with static values. You can't use a function result in the initialization, so

```
    'password' => sha1('salt'.$this->password)
```

is forbidden. You'll have to do that in the constructor instead.